# How to build out custom view helpers for Rails with an onclick and inline styling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on restructuring my code to clean it up and I'm trying to move over into using view helpers to do this. Right now I have the following in my views file:

```
                <div class="btn-group wkt-btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn share dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SHARE
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:16px;"></span>
                    </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu wk-social">
                    <li>
                        <div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-email">
                            <a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('<%= image_url(book.book_image.to_c)%>'); return false;" class="jssocials-share-link" style="background-color: purple; width: 73px;">Print</a>
                            <i class="jssocials-share-logo"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-email">
                            <a href="mailto:?Subject=Book Subject&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 http://url.com/books/<%= book.book_name %>" class="jssocials-share-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-at jssocials-share-logo"></i><span class="jssocials-share-label">E-mail</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-facebook fb-share-button" id="fbid">
                            <div data-href="http://url.com/books/<%= book.book_name %>" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
                                <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore jssocials-share-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Fsomebooks%2Fbooks%2F<%= book.book_name%>&amp;src=sdkpreparse">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook jssocials-share-logo"></i><span class="jssocials-share-label">Share</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

The only thing I can think of to alter this to a view helper is to go to books_helper.rb and do something like:

```
module BooksHelper
  def social_sharing (media)
   when 'email'
     content_tag(:div, class: 'jssocials-share jssocials-share-email')
   end
end
```

I've barely scratched the service here but I feel as even that is incorrect. I've nothing that's looking for the media type so email is worthless. Plus there's a div class around the href I'm hitting but the href has it's own class and an onclick plus styling. Any nudge would be appreciated. I have **never** built out a custom view helper.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a block...

```
<%= social_sharing 'email' do %>
  <a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('<%= image_url(book.book_image.to_c)%>'); return false;" class="jssocials-share-link" style="background-color: purple; width: 73px;">Print</a>
  <i class="jssocials-share-logo"></i>
<% end %>
```

And define your helper method as...

```
module BooksHelper
  def social_sharing(media, &block)
  case media   
  when 'email'
     content_tag :div, class: 'jssocials-share jssocials-share-email', &block
  end
end
```

But I think that might just make your code more obscure even if it does DRY up the `jssocials` classed divs.  I highly recommend "99 Bottles" by Sandi Metz which amongst other things talks about producing clear, maintainable code.

https://www.sandimetz.com/99bottles/

Comment: This somewhat helps with DRY but just barely. The problem is that I have such different stuff with each shareable item that using view helper is challenging.